# Blank space at the end of the string is not considered space

Tags: jquery

I need to check if there is a blank space at the end of the editable div, however, as per the code below, if I add a space at the end of the editable div, it returns all false in the alert. Now if I add a space at the end and after that a letter, then yes it considers the space. However, I need it to return true by adding only one blank space to the end and not identifying that space after inserting a letter.

HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="tag" name="tag">aaa</div>
```

JQuery

```
var Contador;

$("#tag").on('input',function () {
    Contador = 0; 
    while(Contador < $("#tag").text().length) {
        alert($("#tag").text().substr(Contador,1) === " ");
        Contador = Contador + 1;            
    } 

});
```

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/nb50g8oc/

Comment: Returns false for me in FF @BenM

Comment: Return false for me in Google Chrome and True in FireFox.